# Insert into the salestaxrate table the following rows with tax type = 1

Tags: sql

I have to insert into the table the following rows with a tax type = 1

> ```
> Indiana 7%
> Kentucky 6%
> Ohio 5.5%
> ```

This is the code I have thus far

```
insert into sales.salestaxrate
(stateprovinceid,taxtype,taxrate,name)
Values('13','1','0.07','Indiana')
```

My question is do I need to have the numbers in single quotes or just the name?

Comment: It depends how the fields were created. Normally no.

Comment: Not related to your question, but if the stateprovinceid field identifies the state or province, what is the purpose of the name field?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  Most (if not all) SQL systems will implicitly translate the string value to a numeric value.

Note that if the string value is not translatable to a number you will not get an error *until run-time*:

```
insert into sales.salestaxrate
(stateprovinceid,taxtype,taxrate,name)
Values(13,1,'Seven Percent','Indiana')
```

Whereas if you did not use quotes it would not compile.